# CreateFile fails with last error set to ERROR_INVALID_DATA. What does ERROR_INVALID_DATA means in this case?

Tags: winapi

`CreateFile` api on Windows fails (returning `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`) while opening a memory mapped
file. The last error obtained from `GetLastError` is `ERROR_INVALID_DATA` ?

What does `ERROR_INVALID_DATA` means in this case ?

Comment: You can't open a memory-mapped file with CreateFile().  OpenFileMapping() is required.  So that error code means pretty much what it says.